# How to delete row from session array and again order array list?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a web site which enables user to add or delete their own favorite books. I added "add" and "delete" button every row in page. I can add favorite books in session array and there is no problem about it. But I can not delete a row from "user's favorite book list."

I used jquery, ajax. I could unset row but what I want is delete that row from session completely and order again. Despite the fact that I unset the row, element number of session does not change.

Here is code :

```
    //There are rows in $newdata. That is to say, newdata array is not empty now.
    // I just add newdata array here to show that there is an array called newdata.

    var $newdata = array();

    function delete_row($rowid) {

    if (isset($rowid)) {

    $this->newdata = $this->session->userdata('contents');
    unset($this->newdata[$rowid]['id']);
    unset($this->newdata[$rowid]['name']);
    unset($this->newdata[$rowid]['author']);
    unset($this->newdata[$rowid]['year']);

    $this->session->set_userdata(array('contents' => $this->newdata));

    $contents = $this->session->userdata('contents');

    $i = 0;

        foreach ($contents as $key)         
        {
            if ($key['id'] != "") {
                $i++;

            $this->newdata[$i]['id'] = $key['id'];
            $this->newdata[$i]['name'] = $key['name'];
            $this->newdata[$i]['author'] =$key['author'];
            $this->newdata[$i]['year'] =$key['year'];

            } else {

            }
        }

    $this->session->set_userdata(array('contents' => $this->newdata));

    } else {

        echo "There is no row to be deleted";
    }
}
```

Here is view code(html) :

```
<div>

        <?php 

        if (count($contents)==0) {
        echo 'There is no favorite book';
        } else {

        echo '<table class="table table-striped">';

        $i = 0;
        echo count($contents);
        foreach ($contents as $items) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$items['id'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$items['name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$items['author'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$items['year'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><button id='.$i .' class="delete_row"><b>DELETE</b></button></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;

    }
    echo '</table>';

    }
        ?>
    </div>
```

Here is jquery code :

```
$('.delete_row').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
window.location.href = '/favorite/delete_row/'+id;

 });
```

Comment: I don't know the exact workings of the code, but what I noticed: if (isset($rowid)) { -> Is always true, because the $rowid, is passed by the function. Try to set it to the session variable. Should help a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the del button id. You're using the `$i` variable instead of `$items['id']`. So the JS redirect will send the count int and not the item `id` to the delete page.

Change:

```
echo '<td><button id='. $i .' class="delete_row"><b>DELETE</b></button></td>';
```

Into:

```
echo '<td><button id='. $items['id'] .' class="delete_row"><b>DELETE</b></button></td>';
```

Comment: ya, the problem is about id and $items['id'] and some other problems. Thank you for reply.